# Trying to get selenium working in rails 3 - "WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, capybara

I'm trying to use selenium for the first time in a rails 3 app. (I've used it before with rails 2).  I'm in an rvm which of course has its own gemset.

I first ran a task with capybara, without selenium:

```
#./spec/requests/homepage_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'home page', :type => :request do
  it 'should welcome the user' do
    visit '/'
    page.should have_content('Buddy')
  end
end
```

This ran fine.  I then added a ":js => true" option to the options for describe, which is supposed to make it run using selenium (as far as i know).  And got this error:

```
 Failure/Error: @page.start_new_browser_session
 WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError:
   Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: POST http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/ with body 'cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=%2Afirefox&2=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000&3=&4=' with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}

   You can stub this request with the following snippet:

   stub_request(:post, "http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/").
     with(:body => "cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=%2Afirefox&2=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000&3=&4=", 
          :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
     to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})

   ============================================================
```

It's my first time using capybara and i think my config is just wrong somehow.  Maybe missing some essential gems? I was following this blog post: [Capybara (and Selenium) with RSpec & Rails 3: quick tutorial](http://opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/capybara-and-selenium-with-rspec-and-rails-3/)

Any ideas?

PS, here's my Gemfile contents:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'haml'
gem 'heroku'
gem "heroku_backup_task"
gem 'authlogic', '3.0.2'
gem 'rails3-generators'
gem 'txtlocal', :git => 'git://github.com/epigenesys/txtlocal.git'
gem 'chronic'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'mocha'
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.4"
  gem "webmock"
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.5.2'  
  gem 'capybara', :git => 'git://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git'
  gem 'selenium-client'
end
```

and my Gemfile.lock:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/epigenesys/txtlocal.git
  revision: 66aab6628d4385eda959e4a8bd083cc2c259fea0
  specs:
    txtlocal (0.0.1)
      json

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git
  revision: 9cdf015e28637b7b0d94f5a69f9bc3605455ce22
  specs:
    capybara (1.0.0.beta1)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 0.2.0)
      xpath (~> 0.1.4)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    abstract (1.0.0)
    actionmailer (3.0.7)
      actionpack (= 3.0.7)
      mail (~> 2.2.15)
    actionpack (3.0.7)
      activemodel (= 3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      erubis (~> 2.6.6)
      i18n (~> 0.5.0)
      rack (~> 1.2.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.6.14)
      rack-test (~> 0.5.7)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activemodel (3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.5.0)
    activerecord (3.0.7)
      activemodel (= 3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
      arel (~> 2.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activeresource (3.0.7)
      activemodel (= 3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
    activesupport (3.0.7)
    addressable (2.2.5)
    arel (2.0.9)
    authlogic (3.0.2)
      activerecord (~> 3.0.7)
      activerecord (~> 3.0.7)
    bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
    builder (2.1.2)
    childprocess (0.1.8)
      ffi (~> 1.0.6)
    chronic (0.3.0)
    configuration (1.2.0)
    crack (0.1.8)
    database_cleaner (0.5.2)
    diff-lcs (1.1.2)
    erubis (2.6.6)
      abstract (>= 1.0.0)
    ffi (1.0.7)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
    haml (3.1.1)
    heroku (2.1.2)
      launchy (>= 0.3.2)
      rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
      term-ansicolor (~> 1.0.5)
    heroku_backup_task (0.0.5)
      heroku (>= 1.13.7)
      rake
    i18n (0.5.0)
    json (1.5.1)
    json_pure (1.5.1)
    launchy (0.4.0)
      configuration (>= 0.0.5)
      rake (>= 0.8.1)
    mail (2.2.19)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.6)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.16)
    mocha (0.9.12)
    nokogiri (1.4.4)
    polyglot (0.3.1)
    rack (1.2.2)
    rack-mount (0.6.14)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-test (0.5.7)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.0.7)
      actionmailer (= 3.0.7)
      actionpack (= 3.0.7)
      activerecord (= 3.0.7)
      activeresource (= 3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.0.7)
    rails3-generators (0.17.4)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    railties (3.0.7)
      actionpack (= 3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (~> 0.14.4)
    rake (0.8.7)
    rest-client (1.6.1)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rspec (2.6.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.6.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.6.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.6.0)
    rspec-core (2.6.0)
    rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
    rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
    rspec-rails (2.6.0)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.6.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.4)
    selenium-client (1.2.18)
    selenium-webdriver (0.2.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.1.7)
      ffi (>= 1.0.7)
      json_pure
      rubyzip
    sqlite3 (1.3.3)
    sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
      sqlite3 (>= 1.3.3)
    term-ansicolor (1.0.5)
    thor (0.14.6)
    treetop (1.4.9)
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.27)
    webmock (1.6.2)
      addressable (>= 2.2.2)
      crack (>= 0.1.7)
    xpath (0.1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  authlogic (= 3.0.2)
  bcrypt-ruby
  capybara!
  chronic
  database_cleaner (= 0.5.2)
  haml
  heroku
  heroku_backup_task
  mocha
  rails (= 3.0.7)
  rails3-generators
  rspec
  rspec-rails (~> 2.4)
  selenium-client
  sqlite3-ruby
  txtlocal!
  webmock
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's because you are using webmock. It blocks all outbound HTTP requests.

If you don't need it, remove it from the Gemfile. If you do need it, then you may need to configure it more precisely to your needs:

https://github.com/bblimke/webmock

Answer (score 59):

With this...

```
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(:allow_localhost => true)
```

you allow real web access to your localhost. It's perfect when you need to use Selenium for you application and, at the same time, mock external resources.

Answer (score 18):

We use this to enable normal requests in capybara, and allow selenium's callbacks everywhere, because they are fired after requests are finished.

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:all, type: :request) do
    WebMock.allow_net_connect!
  end  

  config.after(:all, type: :request) do
    selenium_requests = %r{/((__.+__)|(hub/session.*))$}
    WebMock.disable_net_connect! :allow => selenium_requests
  end
end
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Though, I am not sure what the selenium_requests is about.

Answer (score 9):

To improve on @grosser code

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before do
    WebMock.enable!
    if Capybara.current_driver != :rack_test
      selenium_requests = %r{/((__.+__)|(hub/session.*))$}
      WebMock.disable_net_connect! :allow => selenium_requests
      WebMock.disable_net_connect! :allow => "127.0.0.1:#{Capybara.current_session.driver.server_port}" # this only works for capybara selenium and capybara-webkit
    else
      WebMock.disable_net_connect!
    end
  end

  # for connections where we need to have network access we just tag it network
  config.before(:each, :network => true) do
    WebMock.disable!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

`WebMock.disable_net_connect! allow_localhost: true`

Answer (score 3):

In my specific case my problem was in [evergreen](https://github.com/abepetrillo/evergreen) (javascript rspec).

I added:

```
WebMock.disable_net_connect! :allow_localhost => true
```

To my environments/env*.rb because evergreen doesn't load rspec helpers.

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me! My circumstance is that I'm trying to run rake assets:precompile with asset_sync to push the assets to Amazon S3 after my tests succeed. The Webmock gem was preventing the asset push, even though I had updated my spec_helper.rb with `WebMock.disable_net_connect!(:allow => /s3.amazonaws.com/, :allow_localhost => true)` I had to updated environments/test.rb with this line and then it started working, thanks to this answer @carlosveucv

Answer (score 3):

Good suggestions here. Another, more fine-tuneable, solution:

```
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(
  allow: [
    'localhost',
    'dynamo:8000',
    'pact-broker:81'
  ]
)
```

Works especially well for whitelisting docker-compose containers!