# send GET request from rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get json from some url in rake task. how I can achive that?

I used this code

```
require 'open-uri'
content = open(my_url).read
logger.info content
```

but it throw `WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError` 
it saying stub this request but how I can get responce from stub_request dont know

from controller it works fine

Comment: follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980856/trying-to-get-selenium-working-in-rails-3-webmocknetconnectnotallowederror

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the `webmock` gem in the test group:

```
# Gemfile
# ...
group :test do
  gem 'webmock'
end
```

Or allow webmock to connect to the net if you are invoking the rake task in a test:

```
WebMock.allow_net_connect!
```

https://github.com/bblimke/webmock

Comment: I need webmock in production/development. one service is giving json api and I want to fetch that json and save my objects to DB

Comment: I added require 'webmock'
include WebMock::API but how to get response that I not figured out yet

Comment: but yes Added WebMock.allow_net_connect! and now I able to get response...thanks bro..